# How to debug Pascal runtime error?

Tags: runtime, pascal

I have a Pascal program built with TMT compiler that runs on Windows 95. Sometimes it fails with a runtime error like:

```
Error 207 at <adress>
```

I would like to at least determine where the error actually occured.

Comment: RT error 207 is a floating point error. At least in turbo pascal that used to be hard to locate, since the error is reported somewhere after the actual error. If you have the source and the error address (and the map file), you can try to locate it from the IDE. If not, you have to narrow it down by outputting some debug strings.

Comment: I am sorry to ask this question, but what is map file? How can i get or generate one?

Comment: It is a compiler switch. Just look in docs how to do that.

Comment: A "map file" shows what addresses are assigned to the symbols/identifiers in the program.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on whatever RTE routine TMT has, and then examine the stack in the debugger when the failure happens. RTE 207 is division by zero 9 times out of 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 207 is generally an Invalid floating point operation. This is the case in both [free pascal](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userap4.html) and [TMT's framework pascal](http://www.frameworkpascal.com/helphtml/run_errors.htm).

Sometimes this occurs when you do not return a value from your functions. Try checking that you assign return values in functions like these:

```
function yourFunction(x:real) : real;
var
  someValue : real;
begin
  someValue := 42;
  yourFunction := someValue;
end;
```

In this case you should make sure that you are assigning your return

```
yourFunction := someValue;
```

A 207 error gennerally means that you have some variable that hasn't been
initialized properly.